# User controls to load asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

We are developing a winform application that does data intensive work. Our queries (BI tasks) can take up to a minute to conclude. We have four important processes, and we want to show their state in one single window. With that in mind, we have developed four user controls, each one shown in our main form. There are three researchers working on their own user controls, and we are integrating them on the main application.

The problem is, when one user control is refreshing, the application will freeze. What should my approach be to make the user controls refresh asynchronously? Is there a solution that I can use, in order to create a Base class or interface that will force the developers of the other controls follow the same method?

Comment: Do your queries on different threads, I would look at backgroundworker

Comment: Yes, but the problem is to force others to use the same interface. Is there something I can do in that regard?

Comment: btw, all the user controls are custom controls that inherit from a base control we have developed which enables us to use a common interface for each control. Maybe I can modify the base control somehow to force a methodology upon everyone developing custom controls.

Comment: It's hard to say without example code layout, it may be possible to insert a base class with a doquery method. Do you have an example query call

Comment: Basically, we have a Refresh() method that we use. This method is called on FormLoad or any time someone refreshes the window. Queries are very ugly: A number of queries fetching data from a database, doing stats (correlations, searching for patterns... )on those records and displaying them visually on the form (in a grid, chart, custom shapes etc).

Comment: Just use a form of threading (Bgw, Threadpool) to execute the queries. There is no requirement all controls do it the same way.